# Website showing differently on Ipad/Iphone simulator vs real Device

Tags: html, css, ipad, cross-browser, mobile-safari

I have searched lots of `iPad / iPhone simulators`...tested my website. Website is looking good on almost all simulators...but when i open the website in real iPad every thing is going wrong...

As i can't inspect etc on device...so its difficult to know things which are going wrong and can't adjust accordingly...any better solution for this?

```
http://ipadpeek.com/
```

This simulator was close but not enough...

Sorry i can't share website link.

Comment: Do you have a mac? Have you used the ipad simulator that comes with XCode? I use it all the time and I haven't seen any differences between the simulator and actual site... yet.

Comment: no i don't have MAC. any thing for xp or 7 ?

Comment: Hmm... I don't see any real solution for you other than to get a mac and use the real ipad simulator. Also, since the ipad runs safari as it's browser and safari is actually webkit and webkit is what Google Chrome is built on, you can get a good indication of how an ipad will behave by testing in Chrome. Other than that... I got nothing.

Comment: Thats the sad world of MAC isolation. That apple should just die. Its more and more complicated to work with them if you don't have an mac, and sure i wont buy a mac to develop just for apple. Simple we stop supporting mac and apple world all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really good service that I use is [Browserstack.com](http://browserstack.com) and simulates all versions of most devices out there, I've found that there are next to no differences other than the fact that they're simulated.

Comment: thanks for the share. this is good link only issue i have with this its not free!

Comment: Unfortunately not, but you can try it for nothing. It's not overly expensive, and it's significantly cheaper than buying loads of devices to test on.