# Website looks different on actual mobile device than with spoofed user agent on desktop

Tags: css, mobile

I'm learning HTML and CSS. I made this site at [No longer exists, sorry. Lesson learned: post the code].

When I view the site on an iPhone or iPad, the three images on the bottom are vertically stacked. When I view the website on Chrome using the Developer Tools, or "User-Agent Switcher for Chrome" (plugin), or mobiletest.me (website), and emulate an iPhone or iPad, the images appear horizontal and perhaps squashed.

The vertical stacking is more usable anyhow, but (1) I would like to know how to reliably test my website on iPhone, iPad, etc. without a physical device, and (2) I would also like to know why these tools and services aren't consistent with the device they're emulating?

*UPDATE*: Actually, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17770497/201891) accurately mimicked the actual device, but can you answer my second question? I would like to be able to rely on Chrome Developer Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These tools are not intended to "emulate", but to merely pass the correlating user-agent string for any site that may be sniffing the user agent for any reason (conditional CSS etc.) Browserstack.com or the physical device itself is a sure way to test sites consistently, but for a cost.

Comment: Are there three factors at play (1) user-agent string, (2) screen size, and (3) browser, e.g. iOS Safari? You're saying that tools like Chrome Dev tools can handle (1) and (2), but for (3) I need more "power".